# Google maps map type button UI

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to create a button for "map type" in my android project.

I've checked the docs here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings

And I don't find a way to enable "map type" button. 
I've seen in the javascript guide this ui: 
[image: gm]

On the left-upper corner is the "satelite" or "map". (Auto translated...) 
Is there a way to enable this buttons in android ?
Or do someone have good mimic of them? 
Thanks

Edit: 
I used this style of button:
https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/layers-in-circular-button_56599#term=layers&page=1&position=92

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom ui buttons and on their click listener use

```
mMap.setMapType();
```

function and pass type of map in this function as an argument
eg. HYBRID,NORMAL etc.

Comment: Yes i've done it already, but I want the Google's original button. I'm wondering is there a way to get it, or if someone already created a similar one.